# Changing the background of an edit control on getting focus

Tags: winapi, mfc

I want to change the background color of an edit control (i.e. regular EDIT window class) in that control's EN_SETFOCUS. I know that I should handle WM_CTLCOLOR, do SetBkColor() on the DC I get, and return a handle to a brush with the background color. HOWEVER, when I do that from EN_SETFOCUS, my control isn't invalidated or redrawn properly. Basically I get a 1-pixel border in the wrong color around my text; so a rectangle within the black border that is already around the control itself. If I move my mouse cursor over the control, some parts of that wrong border are redrawn correctly, and sometimes the whole artifact disappears after a small amount of time, as if some timer is causing a complete redraw.

I have tried invalidating the control in various places, RedrawWindow, SelectRgn(NULL) on the DC, playing with wS_CLIPCHILDREN and -SIBLINGS of the dialog, invalidating the dialog on the rect the control is at, but none of this works. I have also found a vague reference to a similar problem online in a post from 2001 (!) but no solution. Has anyone ever encountered this? Any ideas on other things I could try?

FWIW, this is using VS9 on WinXP, and using MFC, but I've also send messages 'by hand' and that didn't change anything, I don't think MFC in this case is the culprit. Of course I could be wrong :)

Edit:

Code of the dialog of the screenshots below (minimal sample) is here: http://pastebin.com/zepdhdp5 . This is a small wizard-generated app - nothing special, the full source code can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8nxaryoo0vclue/edit_control_redrawing_sample.zip .

The control looks like this after it gets focus:

[image]

and like this when it loses focus:

[image]

As you can see, it looks like there a border around the text area that doesn't get invalidated.

I have tried to reproduce this with pure win32, but when I don't use commonctrl6, it doesn't exhibit the problem. I can't manage to get commonctrl6 to work in win32 though, so I'm suspecting now that it's got something to do with that.

Comment: Could you show the relevant points of your code ?

Comment: You are not using a standard visual style renderer, visible from the strange looking Close button icon.  I'd start there first.

Comment: I am, the dialog doesn't have a close button, the button you see there is added by UltraMon. I removed all buttons to make the sample as short as possible, but I didn't notice it when making the screenshot; just to be sure I just closed Ultramon and tried again and the behavior was the same.

Answer (score 5):

Well what do you know - after another day of intermittently attempting various things and trying different angles in google searches, I found the magic keyword: non-client area invalidation. Which led me to http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?307470-Invalidate-NC-area , which contains the solution:

```
SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_DRAWFRAME);
```

(in the SetFocus/KillFocus handlers)
My theory of what's going on is that the commonctrl6 visual styles manager treats the border around the edit control as non-client area, and miscalculates the area to be invalidated by one pixel when the control gets the focus. SWP_DRAWFRAME seems to be the only thing that forces a complete update of the control, RedrawWindow() with RDW_FRAME didn't cut it.

Ah well, hopefully my question here at least saves someone down the line from wasting his time like I have...

Answer (score 1):

Write this answer for others which maybe will have the same problem :)

```
//static variable, which is once create on the begin of function
static HBRUSH red_brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));

(...)

  case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:

        //operating window
        if((HWND)lParam == example)
        {
            //static flag redraw - have to static
            static int flag_redraw;

            //set background color: red
            SetBkColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(255, 0, 0));

            //once redraw window
            if(flag_redraw == false)
            {
                //Invalidetion of client area - last argument
                //may have value false
                InvalidateRect(example, NULL, true);

                //change value of flag_redraw
                flag_redraw = true;
            }
            
            //when the window is redrawing, communicate WM_CTLCOLOREDIT is proccessed - in this case musn't to again invalidation its region
            else
                //reset redraw flag
                flag_redraw = false;
                
          //return red_brush
          return (BOOL)red_brush;
        
  break;
  //case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT
```

Maybe solution is not ellegant, but working :)